# Getting NOT INSTALLED when installing apk on real device?

Tags: installation, android

I have tried installing my .apk file on device but it stops saying Not Installed . I have checked minsdk and other issues but still getting same error. What else should i try?

Comment: There's usually some information on LogCat which can be helpful.

Comment: Post your lagcat message

Comment: How are you installing? Are you running it through eclipse, using the android command line tool or downloading it through the browser?

Comment: No, just installing the apk file onto the device!

Comment: That's not really answering my question ;) How are you getting the apk-file onto the device?

Comment: just send the apk file to the device and installed it using installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

1. Make sure you can install from other locations than market. Goto Settings->Applications and check the 'Unknown sources' checkbox.
2. The installation will fail if you already have the app installed with a different signature. Manually uninstall the app on your phone.

Edit: Also, is the apk signed with a release key? If so, you might want to verify that the signing/package aligning was done correctly.

Comment: Even after uninstalling app is you are not able to installed app the try to uninstall app using abd.


'adb uninstall your.package.name'

Answer (score 0):

Check if your phone's internal memory is full.

Either free up some space or edit your AndroidManifest.xml to include the installLocation property

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

See more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html).

Comment: Thanx ...but my device have 8 GB of free memory